# String nonce não está a ser gerada

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, formulário

Estou a usar a [API da braintree](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/overview) e consigo colocar o [dropin form](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/hello-client/javascript/v2#demo) deles na página:

```
var braintreeToken = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.brainTreeToken));

braintree.setup(
    braintreeToken,
    "dropin", {
        container: "payment-form"
    });

...
```

Eis o resultado:

[image: Form]

Na documentação deles  diz `braintree.js will add a hidden input named payment_method_nonce to your form`, ou seja, é adicionado um campo escondido com o valor do nonce.

No meu controller, recebo esse campo no FormCollection mas vem sempre como uma string vazia. Não vem nula, vem vazia.

```
[HttpPost]
public void CreateTransaction(FormCollection collection)
{
     string payment_method_nonce = collection["payment_method_nonce"];
```

A string acima vem sempre vazia. Supostamente, traria uma string nonce para poder fazer a transação. Como resolver isto?

## EDIT

O form que escrevo na view é:

```
<form id="createTransactionForm" method="post">
    <div id="payment-form"></div>
    <input type="submit" value="Test - Pay">
</form>
```

A div de id="payment-form" vai ser preenchida com o dropin da braintree.

Usando o inspector do browser pode-se ver o HTML resultado final, que resulta num form dentro de outro. Já me perguntei se isto está correcto, se o form que eu escrevo é necessário, e sim, é assim mesmo.

O resultado:

[image: Form]

Comment: O que vc manda no seu ajax?

Comment: Nada, só faço submit do form. Supostamente, com os dados do cartão de crédito inseridos, ele devia gerar um nonce, que por sua vez é enviado para o controller. O nonce é um código que se envia para o braintree e eles através do código conseguem decifrar os dados do cartão

Comment: Coloque por favor na sua pergunta o código do Form.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, adicionei o form ao post

Answer (score 0):

Para funcionar, `payment_method_nonce` precisa ser criado como um campo `<input>`. Pode ser `type=hidden`. No seu caso, o campo não está sendo criado desta forma.

Uma sugestão seria você criar o campo vazio e preencher usando algum comando JS:

```
<form id="createTransactionForm" method="post">
    <div id="payment-form"></div>
    <input type="hidden" name="payment_method_nonce" value>
    <input type="submit" value="Test - Pay">
</form>
```

Comment: O campo existe, ele é criado automaticamente, daí eu conseguir apanhá-lo no meu controller. A questão é que ele nunca é preenchido. Supostamente, ao fazer submit, o js da braintree devia pegar nos dados do cartão de crédito, criar um nonce (que os representasse) e o form seria submetido com esse nonce

Comment: Bom, aí você tem que ver uma forma de preencher isto manual. Acho que a API deles não está funcionando a contento.

Comment: A API deles deve estar a funcionar pois a braintree tem muita gente a usá-la. Acredito mais que há alguma coisa que eu não estou a fazer correctamente. Já contactei o suporte deles também, deixa ver o que dizem